# Object.GetType() source code

Tags: .net

How is `object.GetType()` implemented in .NET?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's implemented in the runtime itself, so there is no C# source-code for it.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern Type GetType();
```

`MethodImplOptions.InternalCall` is used for functions which have a "magical" implementation inside the runtime itself.

For the normal .net implementation you won't find it at all since its closed source. With Rotor or Mono you'll most likely find in their c/c++ runtime source-code.

I assume it just uses the marker pointer at the beginning of each instance to get to the class information which then contains a field to get to the managed `Type` instance, possibly creating it on demand.

Comment: by runtime, do you mean in **clr.dll** (a.k.a **Common Language Runtime**) ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161120/whats-the-point-of-methodimploptions-internalcall

Answer (score 2):

I've found an article that explains how `Object.GetType()` works in great detail:

[How does Object.GetType() really work?](https://tooslowexception.com/how-does-gettype-work)

The source code mentioned in this article is now open source in [dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) on GitHub.

- [FCIntrinsic "GetType" in `ecalllist.h`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.4/src/coreclr/vm/ecalllist.h#L93)
- [ObjectNative::GetClass in `objectnative.cpp`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.4/src/coreclr/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp#L197)
- [MethodTable::GetManagedClassObjectIfExists in `methodtable.inl`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.4/src/coreclr/vm/methodtable.inl#L1498)
- [MethodTable::GetManagedClassObject in `methodtable.cpp`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.4/src/coreclr/vm/methodtable.cpp#L3787)

Comment: Try include the answerin the thread since links can be down in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is implemented as part of the engine itself, so it is entirely possible that the "source code" for this is c++ and not published (except perhaps for mono etc).

Either way: I can't think of a scenario where you would **need** this... If you want to know how the type metadata is associated with the object, look at the CLI spec - ECMA335

Comment: so the GetType source code resides in the Common Language Runtime ?