# Is static extern void Buffer.InternalBlockCopy part of .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I study how [FileStream is implemented in C#](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs) and in the Read(..) method I can see:

```
n = ReadCore(_buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
...
Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(_buffer, _readPos, array, offset, n);
...
```

Where Buffer.InternalBlockCopy points to definition (bellow) in [buffer.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/buffer.cs,636e4f5bf81c5be1). The method BlockCopy is defined as static extern.  Where is this method defined? It is part of .NET? It is managed or native?

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public static class Buffer
{
    // Copies from one primitive array to another primitive array without
    // respecting types.  This calls memmove internally.  The count and 
    // offset parameters here are in bytes.  If you want to use traditional
    // array element indices and counts, use Array.Copy.
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    public static extern void BlockCopy(Array src, int srcOffset,
        Array dst, int dstOffset, int count);
..
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: [What's the point of MethodImplOptions.InternalCall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161120/whats-the-point-of-methodimploptions-internalcall#11161727)

Comment: If you look around the coreclr repo you can usually find these methods (of course this is the core clr implementation not the full .net framework). This one is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/2583ce936776a0eac31df904e41d5119840c203b/src/vm/comutilnative.cpp). Look for Buffer::BlockCopy.

Comment: @mikez Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Now I see that in Core it is few checks and memmove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the [`extern` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern) means that the method is defined *outside C# code*, and the

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
```

means that it calls a method defined inside Common Language Runtime.

After [`MethodImplOptions` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The call is internal, that is, it calls a method that is implemented within the common language runtime.