# Why can't I get the MethodBody of GetType()?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

Let's say I have this line:

```
MethodBody getTypeMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("GetType").GetMethodBody();
// getTypeMethod is null
```

Why is `getTypeMethod` null? How can I get the `MethodBody` of the `GetType()` method?

Comment: did you try from something other than System.Object?

Comment: @StingyJack Yup, tried with `System.String` and `System.Int32` and still no luck.

Comment: Looks like the answer is that it's a magic call into CLR internals (not too surprising): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056788/object-gettype-source-code

Comment: @EdPlunkett That must be it. Since `GeType()` is `extern`, it does not have a method body, hence the `null` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got to the answer yourself, but just to confirm, `Object.GetType()` is an external method and external methods does not have a method body specified.

From C# specs 10.6.7

> When a method declaration includes an extern modifier, that method is
>   said to be an external method. External methods are implemented
>   externally, typically using a language other than C#. Because an
>   external method declaration provides no actual implementation, the
>   method-body of an external method simply consists of a semicolon.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110706/how-does-extern-work-in-c)'s more elaborate answer.